# Slow query becuase of join on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `deposit_slips` & `deposit_slip_books` as in this example :

```
deposit_slips

id      number      deposited_at
1       10011001    2019-01-01
2       10011002    2019-01-02
3       1001200     2019-01-03
4       1001201     2019-01-04
4       1001203     2019-01-05

deposit_slip_books

id      number_start        number_end
1       10011001            10011020
2       1001200             1001210
```

I used this query :

```
select 
    deposit_slip_books.id, 
    deposit_slip_books.number_start,
    deposit_slip_books.number_end,
    COUNT(deposit_slips.number) AS used,
    MIN(deposit_slips.deposited_at) as first_usage,
    MAX(deposit_slips.number) AS last_entered
from deposit_slip_books
left join deposit_slips
    on deposit_slips.number >= deposit_slip_books.number_start
    and deposit_slips.number <= deposit_slip_books.number_end
    and CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slips.number) = CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slip_books.number_start) 
group by deposit_slip_books.id
```

The query gives me this result, which is what I need, but it is very slow, it takes about 1 minute to load and I have (63k deposit_slips) & (2k deposit_slip_books) :

```
id  number_start    number_end      used        first_usage     last_entered
1   10011001        10011020        2           2019-01-01      10011002
2   1001200         1001210         3           2019-01-03      1001203
```

I'll be grateful if you can show me a better way to do this, thank you.

EDIT :

Columns types :

- `number` : VARCHAR
- `deposited_at` : DATE
- `number_start` : VARCHAR
- `number_end` : VARCHAR
- I need to have the CHAR_LENGTH, because I have deposit_slips with either 7 or 8 numbers, and they should be joined separately.

EDIT 2 :

Tables Schemas :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deposit_slips` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `deposited_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deposit_slips_number_index` (`number`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=617697 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deposit_slip_books` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number_start` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_end` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `number_start_number_end` (`number_start`,`number_end`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=175262 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I need to join these 2 tables to get a result of :

- `number_start` : the column value from `deposit_slip_books`
- `number_end` : the column value from `deposit_slip_books`
- `used` : how many `deposit_slips` found in inside the range defined between ( `number_start` & `number_end` in `deposit_slip_books` table
- `first_usage` : the first `number` found in `deposit_slips` table inside the range defined in `deposit_slip_books` table
- `last_entered` : the last `number` from `deposit_slips` table that is inside the range found in `deposit_slip_books` table ( between `number_start` & `number_end` as I mentionned before )

Comment: Make `deposit_slips.number` a numeric column, or if text, then left pad all values to the same width using zero.  Then, you can try to create an index to make the join faster.

Comment: why you are using CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slips.number) = CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slip_books.number_start)  ???

Comment: @scaisEdge Because the number is probably stored as text, and a simple inequality by itself is not sufficient.

Comment: update your question and add  your table schema   ..

Comment: The number is stored as text, and I numbers with leading zeros, and I have the `number` column indexed in `deposit_slips` table

Comment: Try to maintain a foreign key in between these two tables and Use LEFT JOIN With something like "left join deposit_slips
    on deposit_slips.id >= deposit_slip_books.deposit_slips_id"

Comment: If possible, I would change the table structure to using numeric instead of varchar.

Comment: @DRapp I can't use numeric because `number` column can have numbers with leading zeros

Comment: @dwix, leading zeros is an output formatting requirement, not a how final data is stored.  You can always force a number to show on a screen, or print in a report with leading zeros, but storing and comparing in queries should be on easiest type...

Comment: @DRapp It is not for formatting, the number with leading zeros is the actual number of the deposit slip ( which is the reference number in a physical paper for that deposit slip )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up selecting everything from `deposit_slip_books` and looping through the collection in PHP (Laravel), I did something like this :

```
$data = DepositSlipBook::all()->map(function($book) {

    $deposit = DepositSlip::select([
        \DB::raw('COUNT(deposit_slips.number) AS used'),
        \DB::raw("MIN(deposit_slips.deposited_at) as first_usage"),
        \DB::raw('MAX(deposit_slips.number) AS last_entered'),
    ])
    ->where('deposit_slips.number', '>=', $book->number_start)
    ->where('deposit_slips.number', '<=', $book->number_end)
    ->where(\DB::raw('CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slips.number)'), '=', strlen($book->number_end))
    ->first();

    $book->used = $deposit->used;
    $book->first_usage = $deposit->first_usage;
    $book->last_entered = $deposit->last_entered;
    return $book;
});
```

Not the best solution, but it takes 1 second to load, which is obviously better than 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have proper indexes  on

table  deposit_slip_books composit imdex  on column (number_start, number_end)

and

table deposit_slips column (number )

and if is possible try avoid the char_length compare

```
select 
    deposit_slip_books.id, 
    deposit_slip_books.number_start,
    deposit_slip_books.number_end,
    COUNT(deposit_slips.number) AS used,
    MIN(deposit_slips.deposited_at) as first_usage,
    MAX(deposit_slips.number) AS last_entered
from deposit_slip_books
left join deposit_slips
    on deposit_slips.number >= deposit_slip_books.number_start
    and deposit_slips.number <= deposit_slip_books.number_end

group by deposit_slip_books.id
```

Comment: I need to have the `CHAR_LENGTH`, because I have `deposit_slips` with either 7 or 8 numbers, and they should be joined separately

Comment: but are two different values ..  and then  you don't need  to check the length

Comment: Even if I removed the `CHAR_LENGTH` it is still extremely slow though.

Comment: have you added  the composite index  as suggested  once you have remove the char_length check ???'

Comment: Yes, `ALTER TABLE deposit_slip_books ADD INDEX number_start_number_end (number_start, number_end);`

Comment: and for the table  deposit_slips  on column number  ?? ,,,  and have you others  index on the columns involved ??

Comment: Yes I have indexed the `number` column on `deposit_slips` table

Comment: try update your question add both the tables  schema and the explain plan for the query  ..

Comment: @saisEdge Did you understand what I'm trying to get as a result ?

Comment: yes  ..  but  the only way for improve performance are related the better where clause (as remove the unuseful  CHAR_LENGTH compare) and a proper indexes 
  eventually with composite index  .. these are already done .. so  there are not others  valid action for sql tuning  ..  the others  way for tuning is related  to db config (partition, storage ,,,,)  and hw fetaures disk type .. memory size .. ( and i don't things this is your question )   anyway for 63k  row in join with  2k row the time seem too much to me  .. have you tried  exit to the sqlide or sql console a retry?

Comment: Yes I did. And I'm using Laravel so I think I'll just select everything from both tables without join, and then do the rest on the PHP side, it will maybe be faster but it will cost a lot of memory I guess

Comment: This feels natural to do but B tree is not really meant to index possible (overlapping) start and end ranges like this..deposit_slips.number >= deposit_slip_books.number_start matches alot and deposit_slips.number <= deposit_slip_books.number_end matches alot then the many matches needs to be merged where both conditations are true

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok when you use **deposited_at** in where condition.
To get results for a year, you have to run the foll query 12 times and you can index **deposited_at** to get performance

```
select 
    deposit_slip_books.id, 
    deposit_slip_books.number_start,
    deposit_slip_books.number_end,
    COUNT(deposit_slips.number) AS used,
    MIN(deposit_slips.deposited_at) as first_usage,
    MAX(deposit_slips.number) AS last_entered
from deposit_slip_books
left join deposit_slips
    on deposit_slips.number >= deposit_slip_books.number_start
    and deposit_slips.number <= deposit_slip_books.number_end
    and CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slips.number) = CHAR_LENGTH(deposit_slip_books.number_start) 
where
deposited_at between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
group by deposit_slip_books.id
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with what I asked.